# XSLT to display news item images with consistent size

Tags: image, xslt, image-resizing, image-size

I have a RSS XML news file, which contains a list of items inclusive of a URL to an image.  I also have an associated XSLT.

The problem is that the image sizes are not consistent and I want to limit the image sizes, resize them, to a nice thumbnail.

How would I modify the XSLT to accomplish that?

XML Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version ="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Company Name</title>
        <description>Company description</description>
        <link>http://www.mycompanyurl.com</link>

        <item>
            <title>News Item Title</title>
            <link>http://www.whateverurl.com/</link>
            <category>Space</category>
            <pubDate>12 April 1961</pubDate>
            <description>Software to reduce your job search to a half hour per day. all major job sites, job boards, classifieds. unemployment paperwork, CRM, interviews, more</description>
            <image>
                <url>~/App_Data/NewsControl/whatever.png</url>
                <title>Whatever1</title>
                <link>javascript:void(0)</link>
            </image>
            <g:id>1</g:id>
            <g:brand>Whatever2</g:brand>
            <g:condition>whatever3</g:condition>
            <g:price>$whatever4</g:price>
            <g:product_type>Whatever5</g:product_type>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is the associated XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
      <xsl:for-each select="//item">
        <item Name="{position()}" HeaderText="{title}" Text="{description}" NavigateUrl="{position()}" Date="{pubDate}" ImageUrl="{image/url}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Results of First Answer**:

```
<items>
    <xsl:for-each select="//item">
       <item Name="{position()}" HeaderText="{title}" Text="{description}" NavigateUrl="{position()}" Date="{pubDate}" ImageUrl="/Tools/thumber.php?img={image/url}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</items>
```

I made these changes, enabled PHP on the server (testing on from the server and locally), and saw 2 issues:
1. I get no image, merely a no image box.

1. If I try to edit the ImageUrl and tack on a "&W=xxx&H=xxx", the Visual Studio validator complains and throws up errors on the &.

**Update 2**
Here is the latest line in the XSLT:
        http://myserver.com/Tools/thumber.php?img=',image/url)}"/>

The corresponding image section in the XML

```
<image>
    <url>/Products/Jobfish/Images/Boxshots/Jobfish_DVDCaseCD_ShadowOut.jpg</url>
    <title>Jobfish</title>
    <link>javascript:void(0)</link>
```

Comment: This `/Tools/thumber.php?img={image/url}` is wrong, you cannot evaluate as an expression only part of an attribute - it should be `{concat('/Tools/thumber.php?img=',image/url)}`

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has no built in function for resizing or thumbnailing. You will have to use an external processor for that eg. by using a PHP thumbnail generator.

Then replace the original image path with a URL pointing to your thumbnail generator, with the source being the original image.

suppose ImageUrl = mediaserver.xyz/ourlogo.jpg
the new ImageUrl would become myserver.com/thumbnailgenerator.php?src=http://mediaserver.xyz/ourlogo.jpg

Please make shure you select a caching thumbnail library (eg https://code.google.com/p/phpthumbmaker/wiki/ThumberWiki ) , since it will be a serious resource hog if you skip that. Also take into account copyright issues when re-serving these thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I downloaded Thumber and implemented the code with the addition in the update of my post, however I get VS complaining about & symbols and more importantly no thumbnail, just a no-image box.

Comment: _Update: sorry, i did not read your question right : the image is not on your server and the proposed phpthumbmaker is NOT the correct php library for getting external content. So please do not use that one for getting external images. See also "How do i get resized image of external site?" question on stackoverflow_

Comment: At the moment all images are local.  In the XML file, I use the construct "/images/xxxxx.png".